# Storing an observable array in variable and replacing it's content

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How could I replace a observable array's content by storing it in another variable , say for example:

I have an observable array: `var list = self.StateList();`

And I want to do like this:

```
var cities = self.CityList();
//console.log(cities);
 var oldLocation = ko.utils.arrayFirst(cities, function (item) {
     return item.CityId == args.CityId;

 });

 cities.replace(oldLocation, args);
```

But it is showing error cities has no method `replace`,

**UPDATE I tried with this anwser , it some how helped me** I used observable slice method , it helped some how:

```
   var cities = self.CityList();
   var observble = ko.observable();
   observble(cities.slice(0));
```

So my all cities `observable` will be copied into a brand new `observable`

Now i can do what ever i want as it is same observable array of my cities. Somebody can think like why to convert observable array to variable and again converting it to observable array. I have a requirement to send my observable array to a function. If there is any other better solution please post it over here.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
// The observable array
this.CityList = ko.observableArray([{CityId :1 }, {CityId :2 } ,{CityId :3 }]);

// observable array stored in variable. The brackets should not be used if you 
// want to treat the cities variable as an observable array
 var cities = this.CityList;

 // Find a city with id 1.
 var oldLocation = ko.utils.arrayFirst(cities(), function (item) {
     return item.CityId == 1;

 });

console.log(oldLocation);

// Replace the city with id 5
cities.replace(oldLocation , {CityId :5 });

// The values in both arrays will get modified
console.log(cities()[0]);
console.log(this.CityList()[0]);
```

Comment: it is not taking cities() as a argument in ko.utill.arrayFirst

Comment: when we do **var cities = this.CityList;**
the array in the cities variable can be accessed by cities(). i.e value in the observable array.